# Can you not read in cooperative?

Tags: diablo-iii

In cooperative, I am finding books, but when I click on them - they just turn into gold... Does this mean I already have read them or do you not get the lore in multiplayer?

Comment: This just means you already have the book; has nothing to do with whether you playin coop or not. You get the same behaviour in (pseudo) single player I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will only get experience the first time you pick up a specific book.  Any time after, you will only get gold, even if that book was in a different location.

If it is the first time picking up the book, you will hear the dialog, even if you are playing with others.

Comment: Yep, just confirmed this by finding a book I haven't found on my own yet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a single character can only pick up the lore books that would give experience once.

This makes a bit of sense to stop people from server hopping to level by picking up the lore books laying around towns.